# How to hide THIS Window on debugging Xcode?

Tags: xcode

When i debugging with breakpoints Xcode shows me this window on each step over (or continue):
[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSV7d.png)

But i'would rather see this: [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW0Dv.png)

How to say to Xcode to not show me [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSV7d.png) tab???

Answer (score 1):

I found an option in Xcode, to hide this tabs:
Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always show disassembly (uncheck).[picExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqPhJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSV7d.png) you are seeing the debugger console.

You should find following toolbar at it's top -
[image]

Hit the highlighted button and you should get back to Source Editor.

Comment: No, it's just for hiding Debug Area. I found the answer, Thanks ; )